# Can't properly type the following HOC function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I wrote an HOC function that I can't properly type (which is expected as I'm a TypeScript beginner, and even a types beginner). Here is the function:

```js
const withLayout = (LayoutComponent, layoutProps = {}) => (WrappedComponent) => {
  return function WithLayout(props) {
    return (
      <LayoutComponent {...layoutProps}>
        <WrappedComponent {...props} />
      </LayoutComponent>
    )
  }
}
```

I use it in this way:

```js
interface LayoutProps { a: string, b: string }

interface IndexProps { c: string, d: string }

class Layout extends React.Component<LayoutProps> { }

class Index extends React.Component<IndexProps> { }

withLayout(Layout, { a: 'a', b: 'b' })(Index)
```

Here is my attempt to type it:

```js
const withLayout = <LP extends JSX.IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: React.ReactNode }>(
  LayoutComponent: React.ComponentType<LP>,
  layoutProps: LP = {}
) => <WP extends JSX.IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: React.ReactNode }>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<WP>
) => {
    return function WithLayout(props: WP): JSX.Element {
      return (
        <LayoutComponent {...layoutProps}>
          <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        </LayoutComponent>
      )
    }
  }
```

I have several problems, as you an see in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFA24QB2q8A7sDABYAyyAnhACu8ALxwAPNwAKcLAA8YWRgBN0AKQDKADQB0ASUYwowZsFwBBGEeAAjYVnQAyOAG84uTsAA2yyowD8AFyYVDA62HgwAHIQylhwAL4AfAAUNHBwvALCAMIkkIxKMMER%20Dp54ExFACp8YFiSUkkANOlwXvxCMFLEYKjB0nBiLgk0AJRDSRIA6jLyiirq2vqGxqYWVsZ2ik6u7p4%20fkEhkeGhMXGJqW3TUMhg9coVBUUloeX5VYa19eKzSeNJq42hlKDBBFBGHACIJGPhgEw4NMODxOsIUmBev0kVIxsFNLoAKJeLAgIrAjKUuBgiFQtJUqmSNEwZ5feAuHScjrZbpY5IghkZP53B5YJ6fQqGVycnSYiB9BJwAD0AMFQqVWS6rMlMFVDLGAtGGVGNBMiigBDw8U1wh68vQbmQwRYawA5s04DZndZGK7EnQzVgLVa4AY4nI7X09rhvW6PcpYyY-SbcB1UOgbfB5kpVCcytqikyeZHUFM3Cm0%20gw-JZAoc%20hSmEC4ZxNWI1iy-6aOwuJmUpmPY7gmRkGQPV7yDYyIkxik2wagA). I realize that I should allow `layoutProps` and `props` to be an object respectively of the `LayoutComponent` and the `WrappedComponent` props, but I can't really figure out the proper way to communicate it to TypeScript. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't pass a default empty object as `layoutProps` because that won't have the required props.  Your generics basically aren't getting inferred at all so I have to toy with this and see what's up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue #1: Default Props

The argument `layoutProps` must be type `LP` where `LP` is the props of the layout component.  You cannot use an empty object as the default value of `layoutProps` because that won't have the required props.  We cannot have a default value at all because we don't know what `LP` is so we cannot possibly fulfill the requirements of an unknown type.

#### Issue #2: `extends` Type

You are declaring that the props of both the `LayoutComponent` and the `WrappedComponent` must extend `JSX.IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: React.ReactNode }`.  There are no required properties in this type, so *technically* your components should be assignable to it, but the lack of overlap causes Typescript type inference to choke.

We should be getting a more helpful error like "these types have no properties in common". Instead it just doesn't infer the type.  It uses your `extends` clause as the type and then gives you an error that those props `JSX.IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: React.ReactNode }` can't be used as the props of the component because they are missing properties which are required by the component.

We can fix this simply by widening the `extends` condition (or even removing it entirely).  With `LP extends {}`, the actual props of the component get inferred properly.

```
const withLayout = <LP extends {}>(
  LayoutComponent: React.ComponentType<LP>,
  layoutProps: LP
) => <WP extends {}>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<WP>
) => {
    return function WithLayout(props: WP): JSX.Element {
      return (
        <LayoutComponent {...layoutProps}>
          <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        </LayoutComponent>
      )
    }
  }
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/NBzkDN)

Comment: Thanks! I still have some concerns but I guess I'll open another question, as it's something a bit different.